# Design question: searching products or auto labeling products? (searching vs machine learning)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, machine-learning

I'm working on a project, that has many retailers uploading their products information independently, in other words the exact same product might have various name. For instance, new ipad, or ipad or Great ipad etc...

I want to present to the user an intuitive interface so that when he searches for ipad or ipads, he gets as search result one ipad with all the prices juxtaposed. Or maybe 2 search results, the first one with the old ipad with all the prices from different retailers, and another search result with the ipad 2 and also with the prices one next to the other.

Concrete example:
database contains: new ipad 1, ipad 1, great ipad 1, new ipad 2, ipad 2, great ipad 2
when user searches for ipad, he gets:

- ipad1: price of retailer 1 = 100$, price of retailer 2 = 120$ etc...
- ipad2: price of retailer 2 = 100$, price of retailer 2 = 120$ etc...

Is this mainly a search specific problem? OR machine learning, autolabeling?

And does anyone know something that has been implemented like that in Rails3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is duplicate removing problem. Maps, catalogs are dealing with it. The are many solutions to this problem with different success degree.
Most simple one is to identify synonyms and useless words(Great, fun) etc and do items matching using this information. Some unclear case you should send to human for review.

Example "new Apple Ipad" vs "Great ipad" =remove usless word=> "Apple ipad" vs "ipad" =equal by substring/to ambiguous=> equal